# How create Table in Hive with Custom Date format

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am new to Hive, I have created hive table with date columns(2)

```
Create table test(start_date timestamp, end_time timestamp)
row format delimited fields terminated by ",";
```

But by default Hive date format is YYYY-MM-DD
but my data is Like this

```
Input
========
DDMMYYYY    DD-MON-YYYY
01-02-2012  o1-JAN-2012
22-11-2013   02-FEB-2012
```

so I want to create table with two columns in Hive with 2 different Date formats
how can I do that one

Can any tell me the QUERY for creating table with custom date format.

```
create table custom_date(s_date timestamp(DD-MM-YYYY),E_date timestamp(DD-MON-YYYY))  ?
```

Comment: you can use udf to format the input dates then insert it in your table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to create different Timestamp formats in same table, but different timestamp formats can be displayed in output using unixtime.

select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(start_date), 'dd-MM-yyyy'), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(end_time), 'dd-MMM-yyyy') from test;